# assigning a base class pointer to a derived class object created in the free store

Tags: c++, virtual, new-operator

I was experimenting with c++, trying to understand inheritance and wrote the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

class Base1{
public:
    virtual void print_hello() const
    { std::cout << "Base1: Hello!" << std::endl;}
};

class Base2{
public:
    virtual void print_hello() const
    { std::cout << "Base2: Hello!" << std::endl; }
};

class Derived: public Base1, public Base2
{
public:  
    virtual void print_hello() const
    { std::cout << "Derived: Hello!" << std::endl; }
};

int main() {    
Base1* pb1=new Derived;

pb1->print_hello();

delete pb1;

Base2* pb2=new Derived;

pb2->print_hello();

delete pb2;

return EXIT_SUCCESS;}
```

The code compiled ok but when I ran it, I got a run time error:

```
Derived: Hello!
Derived: Hello!
*** glibc detected *** ./a.out: free(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000001b0c018 ***
```

followed by a Back trace and a memory map list

Both cout statements were printed in the screen so I guess the error originates when trying to delete pb2.

If I do not specify the member functions virtual, the code runs ok. The code also runs ok if I reuse pb1 after I delete it (i.e. `pb1=new Derived;`), instead of creating the new pointer pb2. What am I missing here?

PS: I tried the code in Ubuntu 12.04 using both g++ (4.6.4) and icc (2013.3.163)

Comment: Perhaps you could add a destructor on all classes, with some cout statements in it, to see what's going on when deleting the pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are entering in to the wonderful world of Undefined Behavior, in two places:

```
delete pb1;
delete pb2;
```

This is Undefined Behavior because niether `Base1` nor `Base2` have `virtual` destructors, but you are trying to `delete` the objects pointed to through a base pointer.

It might suprise you that the first instance (`delete pb1`) is also Undefined Behavior, because it appears to work.  That's the beauty of Undefined Behavior -- *anything* can happen, even what you were expecting to happen.

As a rule, when using polymorphism your base classes should always have a `virtual`destructor.  In many cases, it can be trivial:

```
class Base1{
public:
    virtual void print_hello() const
    { std::cout << "Base1: Hello!" << std::endl;}
      virtual ~Base1() {}
};

class Base2{
public:
    virtual void print_hello() const
    { std::cout << "Base2: Hello!" << std::endl; }
      virtual ~Base2() {};
};
```

I'll also point out that your hierarchy is somewhat... *unusual*.  Generally multiple inheritence is not needed.  There are usually better ways to accomplish what you're trying to do.  When you do use multiple inheritence, it's almost always a design flaw to have multiple base classes that have member functions with the same name.  You are generally going to get unexpected (but well-defined) behavior.

Answer (score 0):

When you delete an object of a derived type through a pointer to the base type, the base type must have a virtual destructor. Without it you have undefined behavior. So: add a virtual destructor to `Base1` and to `Base2`.